# Checkbox in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way where a checkbox will automatically appear when new data is entered in google sheet? So this will save time for me that whenever new data is entered, there's a corresponding checkbox to it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script to do so:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  var values = range.getValues(); //gets the values on ColA

  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
    if(values[i] != ""){ //this is the condition to check if Column A values is not blank.
      sheet.getRange(2,3,i,1).insertCheckboxes(); //inserts the checkbox on column C per iteration.
    }
  }
}
```

What this does is that it checks Column A if it's not blank, it will add a checkbox on Column C per value on Column A.

Before running the script:

[image]

After running the script:

[image]

For best results, you can associate this function on a trigger by going to App Script > Triggers page like so:

[image]

You have options for onChange, onEdit, onFormSubmit, or onOpen event driven triggers.

References:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcheckboxes

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this and it run successfully! If I may ask what should I add to the code if I would like to insert the checkbox in column C, column D, and column E? Thank you @Century Tuna

Comment: change `sheet.getRange(2,3,i,1).insertCheckboxes();` to `sheet.getRange(2,3,i,3).insertCheckboxes();`. The last parameter inside `getRange()` means the number of columns for the range. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

Comment: Alright! Thank you so much, big help!

Comment: Last question, what if I have 2 rows for my header? :) Thank you! @Century Tuna

Comment: change `sheet.getRange(2,3,i,3).insertCheckboxes();` to `sheet.getRange(3,3,i,3).insertCheckboxes();` since the first parameter for `getRange()` means the starting row for the range

Comment: Also `var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);` to `var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);`

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=INDEX(A2:A10<>"")
```

[image]